# Echo out custom fields in comments

Tags: custom-field, comments, post-meta, comment-form, comment-meta

I am trying to figure out how to echo 4 created fields from a plugin in my theme template for the comment form and customize the comments output as well. The plugin I am using lets me add custom fields to comment_form but I am unable to echo out even one of them in the comments.

The field I am trying to echo in the code below is "$ag_condition". I also tried using the following code in a few variations and couldn't come up with anything that works.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'property',
);
// return a single meta value with the key 'vote' from a defined comment object
$ag_condition = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'agents_condition', true );
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo('<p>' . $comment->comment_author . '</p><p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>');
echo ($ag_condition);
endforeach;
?>
```

I tried seeking support from the plugin forum and this is the only response I got -

> Where $meta['data_name'] is the extra field name you set in our
>   plugin.

```
echo $comment_meta_key = $meta['data_name'];
                $comment_meta_val = get_comment_meta($comment -> comment_ID, $comment_meta_key, true);
```

My full code --

```
<?php
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'property',

);
// return a single meta value with the key 'vote' from a defined comment object
$ag_condition = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'agents_condition', true );
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo('<div id="' . $comment->comment_ID . '">Agent Name ' . $comment->comment_author . 'Phone' . $comment->comment_phone . 'Reply' . $comment->comment_content . '</div>');
echo ($ag_condition);
endforeach;

?><?php comment_form(); ?>
```

Im not sure how to correct it, any help is appreciated.

UPDATE

I tried the code and tried this other code I was trying to use to echo a custom field from the users profile (phone number) with their comment replies.

In the comment list I just call on the function.

>

```
 function format_comment() { 
>     echo '<div class="comment">
>         <p>'. ' $comment_author '.'</p>
>         <p>'.'get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, "phone", true )'.'</p> </div>' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `comment_ID` until you are in the foreach loop. Try:

```
$comments = get_comments($args);

foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo '<div id="' . $comment->comment_ID . '">Agent Name ' . $comment->comment_author . 'Phone' . $comment->comment_phone . 'Reply' . $comment->comment_content . '</div>';
    echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'agents_condition', true );
endforeach;
```

Comment: Hi tried the above code but it still didnt output anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function add_ag_condition($comment_text) {

    global $comment;

    $ag_condition = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'agents_condition', true );

    return $comment_text . $ag_condition;

}

add_filter('comment_text','add_ag_condition');
```

The above would add the "ag condition" after the comment text, which appears to be where you originally wanted it. I cannot, of course, test it, since I don't have your comment_meta set-up and can't check all details. EDIT: (I do have to wonder though about how you're using it.)

You can add it at various locations, for instance after 'comment_reply_link' if you want it at the very end of the comment box. (Look through https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/comment-template.php for other filter options.)

Comment: Hi, I ended up abandoning that plugin. I am trying to do the same with another though, maybe you can help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204510/how-to-echo-values-from-rating-system-plugin-with-raty